# Autodesk forge, model coordination clashes not detected

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

Working with the model coordination Api and 3 revit models (DOC1,DOC2 and DOC3), where DOC2 is a copy of DOC1 with edited family geometry, resources from "
GET https://developer.api.autodesk.com/bim360/clash/v3/containers/:containerId/tests/:testId/resources
" are not detecting any clash between DOC1 and DOC2.

DOC1: only one family, the cylinder, DOC2 is the cube one (cylinder family edited)
[image]

This is the HTTP request I am using:
`

```
router.get('/getClashInstance/:containerId/:modelSetId/:version', async (req, res) => {
  const oauth = new OAuth(req.session);
  const internalToken = await oauth.getInternalToken();
  let apiInstance = new Clash.ClashTestApi();
  let defaultClient = Clash.ApiClient.instance;
  let oauth2AuthCode = defaultClient.authentications['oauth2AuthCode'];
  oauth2AuthCode.accessToken = internalToken.access_token;
  const containerId=req.params.containerId
  const modelSetId=req.params.modelSetId
  const version=req.params.version
     try{
      const clashTest=await apiInstance.getModelSetVersionClashTests(containerId, modelSetId, version)
      const testId=clashTest.tests[0].id
      const resources=await apiInstance.getClashTestResources(containerId,testId)
      //const clashResource=resources.resources[0]
      const clashInstanceResource=resources.resources[1]
      //const documentResource=resources.resources[2]
      const docJson=await  axios({
        method: 'get',
        url:clashInstanceResource.url,
         responseType: 'arraybuffer',  
         decompress:true       
                })
                .catch(function(err){
                    console.log(err)
                })
                .then(function(data){
                    const buffer=data.data
                    let tempJson=JSON.parse(buffer.toString('utf-8')) 
                // console.log(tempJson)
                  return   tempJson                  
                })
      res.json(
        docJson
      )
        //console.log(item)      
     }catch(err){
      console.log("err")
     }
})
```

`

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks in UI, it does not show the clashes of DOC1 and DOC2. API only fetches the results which  the core algorism detected. If the clashes are not available at all, the API will not get them.  So we need to diagnose the core algorism. Could you share a copy of these 3 Revit files?

Comment: Of course, here they are: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yhTb2qfCT2LaVMMvrzlpyMsHPYNf2sM7/view?usp=share_link  Thanks

Comment: My apology for the late response! I missed your update. I am checking with engineer team about this. Thank you for your patience!